# NameError: global name 'MAGIC_PINK' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a project which looks like so:

```
PyBlob
|- __init__
|- Actor
|- Blob
|- Bullet
|- main
|- Player
|- Scene
|- utils
|- Zombie
```

## __init__.py

```
import sys, pygame, cmath
from Actor import Actor
from Blob import Blob
from Bullet import Bullet
from Player import Player
from Scene import Scene
from utils import *
from Zombie import Zombie
```

## utils.py

```
MAGIC_PINK = (255, 0, 255)

# plus a small handful of utility functions
```

## Blob.py

```
from PyBlob import *
class Blob:
    def __init__(self, radius, body_colour=(0,0,0), face_colour=(255,255,0)):
        self.body = pygame.Surface((2*radius, 2*radius))
        self.face = pygame.Surface((2*radius, 2*radius))
        self.body.set_colorkey(MAGIC_PINK)

        #rest of module omitted for brevity
```

This results in the error:

```
NameError: global name 'MAGIC_PINK' is not defined
```

Importing the classes seems to work fine so clearly I am doing something wrong with this MAGIC_PINK variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular import. Python has to import PyBlob.Blob to import PyBlob, and it has to `from PyBlob import *` to import PyBlob.Blob. This is a problem.

When Python tries to run `from PyBlob import *`, it finds that PyBlob is already in the middle of the import process. It can't wait for PyBlob to be ready, because PyBlob won't be ready until Blob is ready, and Blob needs PyBlob. Thus, it assumes that PyBlob is "ready enough", and uses it in its current state. Unfortunately, PyBlob is still missing most of the stuff it's supposed to have, so `from PyBlob import *` doesn't pick up most of the stuff it was supposed to pick up.

To fix this problem, reorganize your code to stop using circular imports, and try to avoid `import *`.

Comment: Since python JIT compiles to bytecode, shouldn't the compiler resolve this prior to runtime? This isn't an issue in other languages e.g. Java.

Comment: @BlaiddDrwg: Nope. The variables a module contains aren't known until runtime; you can put `if today_is_wednesday(): x = 3` in a module, and it'll only have an `x` variable if it's loaded on Wednesday. `from foo import *` doesn't change the name lookup rules to look in `foo` if it doesn't find a global; it looks for all names in `foo` that don't start with an underscore and assigns their current values to identically-named variables in the current namespace.

Comment: There's a very similar issue in Java - not with circular imports (because an import in Java *does* just change some compile-time name lookup rules), but with circular classloading. A Java class can [execute arbitrary code at class loading time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), which can trigger the loading of other classes. If loading a class Foo triggers the loading of a class Bar, and loading Bar triggers the loading of Foo, the JVM will cancel the recursive loading of Foo and use it half-loaded.

Comment: If `Foo.java` contains `static int x = Bar.x; static int y = 3;`, and `Bar.java` contains `static int x = Foo.y`, and `Foo` is loaded first, then `Foo.x` and `Bar.x` will both be `0`. This is not a fun problem to have.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Modularity is hard, maybe I'll just throw everything back into one file; it was working fine before I tried to modularize it.

Comment: Strange that languages will use modules in this half-initialised state. This could lead to some hard bugs. It seems like the sensible thing to do would be to treat it as a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

try `utils.MAGIC_PINK`, you should point out in which file the name is addressed